# Android Facebook SDK login issue with parse sdk

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a weird problem when logging using the `LoginManager` class. I am calling `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(..)` from a fragment to login with the required permissions.

I've debugged as far as I can and I found that the callback request code which returns to the `onActivityResult` of the parent activity of this fragment is wrong. The following piece of code is from the `LoginManager` class which registers the callback for login with some request code.

```
...
CallbackManagerImpl.registerStaticCallback(
              CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode(),
              new CallbackManagerImpl.Callback() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean onActivityResult(int resultCode, Intent data) {
                   return LoginManager.this.onActivityResult(resultCode, data);
                 }
              }
      );
...
```

But when it calls the onActivityResult of the activity it's not the `CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode()` but something else it's like double. For example when i tried to debug and check the values it was something like this:

> CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode() = 64206
>
> requestCode received in Activity class = 129742

and now because of this when callbackManager tries to call the onActivityResult like

> callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

with this requestCode it doesn't find the logincallback from the map to go ahead and it stops right there. I don't know why it's happening as i am using ParseFacebookSDK and when i do login with `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(..)` it works perfectly. Following is the gradle dependencies.

```
...
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile('com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
                module: 'bolts-tasks'
    }
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
...
```

If you can help, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

It worked for me when i tried facebook login from parent activity instead of fragment, it returned the correct request code in onActivityResult of activity this time and it simply worked. This has resolved my problem but still want to understand the problem with fragment here, so if you know please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: please avoid the use of library while Facebook providing pretty much SDK for android.
because as we know parse is in deprecation process. it's a suggestion to you that don't use parse.

Comment: i am using parse as backend and have already migrated it on dedicated app server.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to call `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground` while your user is already logged is not correct, and probably that's why you don't get the callback.

The correct function to call if your user is already logged in, but not linked to Facebook, is `ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground`, meaning that you want to link the user to facebook, not log in to your app (as he is already logged in). [Take a look in the docs for that.](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#facebook-linking)

Comment: Ohkay let me try with that. Thanks for the response.

Comment: What will happen in this case when another user is already logged in with facebook on another device as the documents says that __"The steps that happen when linking are very similar to log in. The difference is that on successful login, the existing ParseUser is updated with the Facebook information. Future logins via Facebook will now log the user into their existing account."__

Comment: That's a different question. Did the answer solve your original question?

Comment: Well it also didn't work with `ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground`, and the request code i get in the activity is still different than **CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode()**. But than i found a strange thing that facebook login or linking is neither working with Facebook SDK nor with ParseFacebookUtils from inside fragment, So i than tried to do the same login from the parent activity and it __Worked.__

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(..)` from a fragment, then expect to receive the correct request code in `onActivityResult` of the fragment, rather than activity's `onActivityResult`.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)). Fragments have their own 'onActivityResult` method. They need not depend on an activity for that.

Isn't it awesome that something that doesn't necessarily require any UI still provides this method by itself :)